# Asp.Net Change Value Without runat server

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, runatserver

I want to set a value. But i can't use runat server on form. Because this form is a post form to paypal. 
I closed runat form and i create a new form;

```
</form>

                <form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/tr/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="info2@gundogdubisiklet.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="TRY">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Gündoğdu Bisiklet E-Ticaret">

<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="12">

<input type="submit"  border="0" name="submit" value="Şimdi Öde" alt="PayPal - Online ödeme yapmanın daha güvenli ve kolay yolu!">
</form>
```

So i cant set the amount value on c#.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh how can i forget. I used like this;

```
<input type="text" name="amount" value="<%= SepetToplam().ToString() %>" />
```